# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar un jtable que obtiene los datos de la BD en tiempo real sin necesidad de oprimir un botón?

Tags: java, mysql, java-swing

Lo que intento hacer es que un `jtable` se actualice automáticamente sin la necesidad de presionar un botón para mostrar que los datos han cambiado en tiempo real, solo quiero que la tabla lea la BD y cambie si es que se han agregado o eliminado datos en tiempo real. 
Soy novato en programación por lo que no se mucho del tema.

```
 void mostrardatos (String valor) {
        conectar cc=new conectar();
        Connection cn=cc.conexion();

    DefaultTableModel modelo=new DefaultTableModel();

     modelo.addColumn("ID");
     modelo.addColumn("Nombre");
     modelo.addColumn("Apellido");

    jTable1.setModel(modelo);
    String sql="";
    if (valor.equals("")){
        sql="SELECT * FROM idconexion";
    }
    else{
        sql="SELECT * FROM idconexion WHERE (id='"+valor+"' OR nombre='"+valor+"'  OR apellido='"+valor+"')";
    }  

    String []datos=new String [3];
    try{
        Statement st=cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);


        while(rs.next()){
            modelo.addRow(new String[]{
                rs.getString("id"),
                rs.getString("nombre"),
                rs.getString("apellido")
            });
        }          

        jTable1.setModel(modelo);
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
    }

}
```

Esta función es la que hace que cuando presione El botón "mostrar" la tabla se refresque y muestre los datos en ella.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias colocar un TIMER para realizar esa acción.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class temporizador {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Creamos una instancia de la clase mostrarHora que implementa
        // la interfaz "ActionListener"
        ActionListener objHora=new mostrarHora();

        // Creamos una instancia de la clase Timer indicando que cada
        // 5 segundos ejecute el metodo "actionPerformed" de la clase
        // mostrarHora que implementa la interfaz "ActionListener"
        Timer objTimer=new Timer(5000,objHora);

        // Iniciamos el timer
        objTimer.start();

        // Esperamos la pulsación de la tecla enter para finalizar el timer
        Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Pulsa la tecla ENTER para finalizar...");
        String valor=entrada.next();
        entrada.close();

        // finaliza el timer
        objTimer.stop();

    }

}

// Clase mostrarHora que implementa la interfaz ActionListener que nos
// obliga a implementar el metodo "actionPerformed"
class mostrarHora implements ActionListener {

    // Definimos el metodo "actionPerformed" para que nos muestre la hora
    // cada vez que sea llamado por el Timer en la linea 16.
    // Este metodo es de la interfaz "ActionListener", por lo que estamos
    // obligados a implementarlo.
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // Mostramos en consola la fecha actual
        Date fechaActual=new Date();
        System.out.println(fechaActual);
    }
}
```

**FUENTE:** https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/codigo/Java/3634-Ejemplo-de-la-utilizacion-de-la-interfaz-ActionListener-para-mostrar-la-hora-cada-5-segundos-con-el-objeto-Timer.html